# geom_point works but geom_line fails with color scale

Tags: r, ggplot2

This is as close to a MRE as I could get. Consider the following code:

```
cld = data.frame(x=c(0.02, 0.05), y=c(0.01, 0.02), variable="aMCA")

colors = list(aMCA = "#FF00FFFF")

ggplot(cld, aes(x=x, y=y, color=variable))+
            geom_point(size=4)+
            scale_color_manual(values=colors)
```

This code works as expected. If I change geom_point to geom_line:

```
ggplot(cld, aes(x=x, y=y, color=variable))+
            geom_line(size=4)+
            scale_color_manual(values=colors)
```

I get the following error:

```
ERROR while rich displaying an object: Error in stats::complete.cases(data[c("x", "y", "size", "colour", "linetype")]): ungültiger 'type' (list) des Argumentes
```

If I change the code to

```
ggplot(cld, aes(x=x, y=y, color=variable))+
            geom_line(size=4)+
            scale_color_manual(values=as.character(colors))
```

it will work and that's fine for the MRE. But it's bad for my use case, where I rely on a certain order in the colors. Also, as the code works as is for geom_point, I feel that this hack should not be necessary. Is there something that I'm missing?

Comment: Both would work if you used `colors = c(aMCA = "#FF00FFFF")`. It's better to use a named vector than a named list.

Comment: You're right! If you make your comment an answer, I'll accept it. I'm curious though: What determines which structure for color scales is acceptable? Is a named vector always ok?

Comment: `?scale_color_manual` states for `value` a set of aesthetic values to map data values to. The values will be matched in order (usually alphabetical) with the limits of the scale, or with breaks if provided. If this is a named vector, then the values will be matched based on the names instead. Data values that don't match will be given na.value.

Comment: I understand that - but it looks to me that sometimes it's okay to use a (named) list and sometimes it's not. Why is this?

Comment: I'm not sure but the answer will probably require digging to how these inputs are handled in `ggplot2` internal functions used in `scale_*_manual()`

Comment: @EJJ Thank you :) I just wondered if there was a special rationale but I just seem to have gotten lucky with the list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if your specific use case is based on some `data.frame` or `list` with the colors mapped to certain values in your plotting data. I would suggest anapproach that I've found useful. I added an additional level/value to `variable` to the `cld` `data.frame`.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(tibble)
# data
cld <- data.frame(x=c(0.02, 0.05), y=c(0.01, 0.02), variable=c("aMCA", "bMCb"))
```

If colors encoded in a named `list`

```
# color mapping as list
colors_list <- list(aMCA = "#FF00FFFF", bMCb = "red")

# using list
ggplot(cld, aes(x=x, y=y, color=variable))+
  geom_point(size=4)+
  scale_color_manual(values=unlist(colors_list))
```

If colors encoded in a `data.frame`

```
# color mapping as data.frame
colors_df <- data.frame(variable = cld$variable, col = c("#FF00FFFF", "red"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

ggplot(cld, aes(x=x, y=y, color=variable))+
  geom_point(size=4)+
  scale_color_manual(values=tibble::deframe(colors_df))
```

[image]